# Spring security with multiple login forms

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring security. I am using Spring security to secure login to the application admin section with a username and password.
However, I have two different login pages in my application admin and user.
Admin and user credentials/details are stored in different tables in the database.

I have searched on internet and know that from spring-security 3.0  we can configure multiple http elements in spring-security.xml

But as I have storing admin and user credentials in different database tables how to execute different query on different login.

Comment: It would be a start by showing your current security configuration (Java or XML)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can do something like this: create 2 authentication-manager

<security:authentication-manager id="manager1">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService1"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:authentication-manager id="manager2">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService2"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

and use them saperately in both login form declarations

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="manager1">
<security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login".....>


<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="manager2">
<security:form-login login-page="/login2" login-processing-url="/login2".....>
```